# Loop through named ranges using two corresponding arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

The loop goes through a named ranged and if a cell matches then it will paste resized range into a different worksheet. I'd like to use one loop for different ranges instead of writing the same code for each range. I thought about using an array, but I don't know how to go about data in column **F** (see below).

The below line of code will paste in the matching data into a different worksheet from columns **A:D**

```
cell.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:= _
           Sheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

This line pastes value from a named range into column **F**.

```
Sheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).Value = Sheets("Boards").Range("UFFCAR").Value
```

Would it be possible to have this loop use two corresponding arrays, i.e.

```
Unit = Array("UFF", "ERF", "DOF") < Data from column A:E
UM = Array("UFFCAR", "ERFCAR", "DOFCAR") Data in column F
```

Full code

```
Sub Test()

Dim cell As Range

With Sheets("Boards")
   For Each cell In .Range("UFF")
        If cell.Value = "CAR" Then
          cell.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:= _
           Sheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
         Sheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).Value = Sheets("Boards").Range("UFFCAR").Value
        End If
    Next cell
End With

Call Test2

End Sub

Sub Test2()


Dim cell As Range
    

With Sheets("Boards")
   For Each cell In .Range("ERF")
        If cell.Value = "CAR" Then
          cell.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:= _
           Sheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
         Sheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).Value = Sheets("Boards").Range("ERFCAR").Value
        End If
    Next cell
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What `Unit` array elements are? The named ranges in discussion? If yes, what about `UM` array?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem, try the next approach, please:

```
Sub testNamesIteration()
  Dim shCI As Worksheet, Unit As Variant, UM As Variant
  Dim El As Variant, cell As Range, i As Long
  
  Set shCI = Sheets("CAR Issues")
  Unit = Array("UFF", "ERF", "DOF") ' Data from column A:E
  UM = Array("UFFCAR", "ERFCAR", "DOFCAR")
  
  With Sheets("Boards")
    For Each El In Unit
         For Each cell In .Range(El)
            If cell.Value = "CAR" Then
               cell.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 4).Copy Destination:= _
                         shCI.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
               shCI.cells(rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).Value = _
                                                    .Range(UM(i)).Value
            End If
        Next cell
        i = i + 1
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

The above code supposes that there are correspondences between both arrays elements. I mean, in case of the first element of the first array, the first element of the second one will be copyed...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly to avoid a second sub, you could reference your arrays via the same array index (e.g. via `Unit(i)` and `UM(i)`; by default the arrays here would be zero-based):

```
Sub doSomething()
    Dim Unit: Unit = Array("UFF", "ERF", "DOF")             '< Data from column A:E
    Dim UM:     UM = Array("UFFCAR", "ERFCAR", "DOFCAR")    '< Data in column F
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(uff) To UBound(Unit)                     ' assumes same boundary as UM
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Boards")              ' fully qualified range reference!
            Dim cell As Range
            For Each cell In .Range(Unit(i))                '< get index i from Unit
                If cell.Value = "CAR" Then
                    cell.Offset(, -3).Resize(, 4).Copy _
                        Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    Thisworkbook.Worksheets("CAR Issues").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 4).Value = _
                        .Range(UM(i)).Value                 '< get index i from UM
                End If
            Next cell
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Hint:**
I'd reference worksheets via the project's *Code(Name)*, e.g.

```
Sheet1.Range(...)
```

instead of

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XY").Range(...)
```

*Note: btw named range `DOF` isn't mentioned in your original code.*